# How are damage penalties on melee attacks calculated?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, attack, damage

Several attacks get only half the Strength bonus to damage - off-hand attacks or attacks from light weapons come to mind.
Of course, main hand, non-light attacks get the full Strength bonus and two handed attacks get 1-1/2 times the Strength bonus.

When Strength is lower than 10 I'm sure main hand, non-light attacks get the Strength penalty to damage.
What about the other two cases? **Do they get the Strength penalty as well or do they get half that? If it's half that, how is half of, let's say, -1 calculated?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The Strength Penalty to Damage Remains Unadjusted**
A Medium creature with Strength 8 who's fighting with two weapons, a longsword in one hand and a short sword in his off-hand, will inflict 1d8-1 points of damage with the longsword and 1d6-1 points of damage with the short sword, for example. The same creature with Strength 6 will inflict 1d8-2 points of damage with the longsword and 1d6-2 points of damage with the short sword.

---

From the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm).

> **Strength Bonus**
>   When you hit with a melee or thrown weapon, including a sling, add your Strength **modifier** to the damage result.
>
> *Off-Hand Weapon*
>   When you deal damage with a weapon in your off hand, you add only ½ your Strength **bonus**.
>
> *Wielding a Weapon Two-Handed*
>   When you deal damage with a weapon that you are wielding two-handed, you add 1½ times your Strength **bonus**. However, you don’t get this higher Strength bonus when using a light weapon with two hands.

Also from the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm):

> **Modifiers**
>   A modifier is any bonus or penalty applying to a die roll. A positive modifier is a **bonus**, and a negative modifier is a penalty.

Emphasis--except in the headers--mine. Thus while the *bonus* may be different, the *other* kind of modifier--the *penalty*--is unchanged.

Comment: The funny thing is I could have found the solution myself if I'd been searching that SRD page for "1/2" instead of for "half". This is it, exactly for the reasons I expected, and my friend who asked me thanks you very much.